# i want to get selected row value from tableview and copy into textfiled for appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

hi all
       i want to get selected row value into textfield so how can i copy the value into the textfiled. so how can i do this...my_combo is textfiled
Code -:

```
var Tab_data = [

     { title:'Row 1', hasChild:true },
     { title:'Row 2', hasChild:true },
     { title:'Row 3', hasChild:true },
     { title:'Row 4', hasChild:true }
];


var tab = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    top:43,
    data:Tab_data
});

tab.selectionIndicator=true;

tab.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

    var ind = e.index;

    if(e.selectRow)
    {
        Titanium.API.inof(' Selected clicked');
        my_combo.value = e.selectRow.title;
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) Create the row and attach the rowid to it, or whatever other data you want to associate to a row.

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
row.rowId = 1;
row.myText = "hello world";
```

2) Add click event listener to the table:

```
tableView.addEventListener('click', selectRow);
```

3) In selectRow function, get the data.

```
function selectRow(e) {
 var rowId = e.rowData.rowId;
 var myText = e.rowData.myText;
 myTextField.value = myText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... i have another problem that how can i use soap based webservice in my apps. kitchensink ex. is not worked properly so can u give me any tutorial or code for it.

Comment: Under Titanium v3.0 I had to add my additional properties in the method constructor as shown here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135791/get-custom-row-data-in-table-click. E.g. _var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
         target: tableOptions[i].target
      });_ - I could then use _e.rowData.target_ in my event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add 'rowid' to each row. And make an eventListener on your table like you did and retrieve the value with 'e.row.rowid'.

Comment: Close, however I think it should be e.rowData.rowid. If e.row works as well then let me know, I've never tried that.

Comment: Thanks for your help... i have another problem that how can i use soap based webservice in my apps. kitchensink ex. is not worked properly so can u give me any tutorial or code for it.

Answer (score 0):

you should put in constructor   like this

```
var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    hasChild:true,
    title:rows.fieldByName('title'),
    rowId:rows.fieldByName('id'),
    path:'nextView.js'

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tab.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

    var ind = e.index;

    if(e.selectRow)
    {
        Titanium.API.inof(' Selected clicked');
        my_combo.value = e.rowData.title;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **e.selectRow** with **e.row** in your code.

```
tab.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

    var ind = e.index;

    if(e.row)
    {
        Titanium.API.inof(' Selected clicked');
        my_combo.value = e.row.title;
    } 

});
```